# I want to access the uid under unique post key. How can i access that post key under post node to access the uid and do my work

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to access the unique post key of a post node.

Database image

[image]

Here is my post reference. child("APosts") is different from database name but i was just checking with different name. Please answer either using this reference or references used in database picture.

```
postRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("APosts");

 Query query=postRef.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(currentUserId);
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    postkey=snapshot.getKey();
                    Log.i("Post Key",postkey);
                    postRef.child("profile_image").setValue(profile_img);
                    postRef.child("fullname").setValue(fullname);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I just updated the code. please check it

Comment: @AlexMamo Please check and tell me what am i doing wrong? how can i access that key mentioned in picture?

Comment: Does this line `Log.i("Post Key",postkey);` print something?

Comment: @AlexMamo it just print the name of the node. Like now i put APosts it shows this  node name

Comment: So the key is correctly printed. Now, what is the exact data that you want to print?

Comment: I have accessed the key but don't know why when i update full name sometimes it works perfectly but often firebase is just doing strange thing. It just continue to update between old and new value. Can you tell me the reason why it doing so?